# Issue using authentication provider in azure mobile services

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to log in to Azure Mobile Service using the authentication token but getting this error: "The authentication token's signature was malformed or signed by a different key."  I am using Facebook as Authentication Provider.

for the record, I have obtained the authentication token by logging in first.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication token you receive from "authenticating first" to Facebook or another social network may be different than the one you would get from authenticating via Azure mobile service to that network. This is why your token would be "sign by a different key". For what it's worth, it's no different than trying to use a token acquired from another site that uses social login and using it in your site. You can only use the token that is signed with your key.